# setting a parameter inside of a bteq script

Tags: sql, teradata

In a bteq script, can I set a variable in the begining of the script and then use it through out the sql statements in the bteq script?

for instance, in TSQL I can do something like....

```
DECLARE @state char(2)
SET @state = 'UT'

SELECT * FROM COLUMN = @state
```

can I do something like this in bteq?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use environment variables like ${state} in shell scripts before calling the bteq script.

Comment: so if I wanted to grab a data point from a table and use it as a variable, I would need a shell script that would first query that data point and store it as a shell variable, then another shell script that passes that variable to the bteq and then runs it?

Comment: I understand your concern. The solution is quite clumsy. There might be some other workarounds for this problem. Unfortunately the BTEQ itself doesn't support variables the same way as in T-SQL. Actually you can use just one shell script that first calls one bteq, initializes the variable and then calls another one bteq.